# Aggressive enderman tag with /summon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to spawn a aggressive enderman?

I am making a slenderman map and want to use /summon to spawn slenderman (enderman with a texture pack). I don't know the data tag.

Answer (score 6):

#### There's no NBT tag for this.

From [this thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2088615-how-to-summon-a-angry-enderman-so-you-do-not-need-to-look-at-it/) on the Minecraft Forum:

> Endermen do not have any extra NBT tags for doing something like this. Endermen attack based on player input; even if we could manipulate whether they were angry or not, there wouldn't be a way to target an unknown player.

A possible workaround would be to force the player to briefly look the enderman in the eye by spawning him directly in front of the player.

The wiki has a list of all [NBT tags per entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Entity_Format).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to summon an enderman which attacks players on sight, you could try this summon command:

```
/summon EnderMan ~0 ~1 ~0 {Anger:1}
```

Or whatever command to summon an enderman but set the "anger" NBT tag to 1. That's it

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Enderman don't have an `Anger` tag. The only mobs that do are Zombie Pigmen. Wolves have an `Angry` tag. Furthermore, neither work correctly with the `\summon` command, this is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-33558) though. All NBT tags per entity are listed [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Entity_Format)